# Apache Airflow task runs twice

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-composer

I'm running Dataflow jobs on GCP by scheduling DAGs with Cloud Composer.
This is my DAG graph. The maf_to_bq_X tasks are grouped together with Airflow `TaskGroup`; they are `BeamRunPythonPipelineOperator` Operators that execute on Dataflow. These taks perform the same operations:

1. Get a file path in `variables_conf`
2. Read and process the file
3. Write the output to BigQuery

I set `max_active_runs=1` and `max_active_tasks=3`.
[image]

Every time I run the pipeline, one of those tasks is repeated twice.
After the `set_variables_conf` task, 3 tasks are taken from the queue and run in parallel; one of these is marked as *up_for_retry* but still in execution on Dataflow. Since there are no errors, the task is completed and marked as successfull but Airflow schedules the task another time.

[image]

This is a big problem because, at the end, I will have duplicates in my BigQuery table.
What's the problem with this DAG?

PS. I've also tried to assign a priority weigth to each task but it still doesn't work

This is the DAG's code:

```py
    with models.DAG(
        "ieo_dima_extraction",
        default_args={
            "start_date": pendulum.today('Europe/Rome'),
            'retries': 3,
            "dataflow_default_options": {
                "project": project_id,
                "region": "europe-west1",
            }
        },
        on_success_callback=cleanup_xcom,
        is_paused_upon_creation=True,
        render_template_as_native_obj=True,
        max_active_runs=1,
        max_active_tasks=3,
        schedule_interval=None
    ) as dag:
        set_variables = PythonOperator(
           task_id='set_variables_conf',
           python_callable=set_variables_conf,
           op_kwargs={'bucket_name': 'dima_landing_area'},
           do_xcom_push=True
        )
    
    list_of_maf = Variable.get('dima_maf_paths', default_var={}, deserialize_json=True)
    mapping_file_path = Variable.get('dima_mapping_path', default_var='')
    dima_bucket = 'dima_landing_area'
    
    with TaskGroup(group_id='process_maf_files', prefix_group_id=False) as process_maf_files:
        if list_of_maf['files']:
            for index, maf_file in enumerate(list_of_maf['files']):
                maf_to_bq = maf_to_bq_job(index, processing_path, maf_file, bq_data_table, dataset_name, temp_location,
                                          staging_location, project_id, dataflow_region, mapping_file_path)
    
    truncate_map_tmp_start = truncate_job("start", dataset_name, bq_mapping_tmp_table, bq_job_region)
    with TaskGroup(group_id='process_mapping', prefix_group_id=False) as process_mapping:
        map_to_bq = mapping_to_bq(update_map_path, bq_mapping_tmp_table, dataset_name, sql_view_file, temp_location,
                                  staging_location, project_id, dataflow_region, mapping_file_path)
        merge_map = merge_job(query_merge, dataset_name, bq_mapping_table, bq_job_region)
        truncate_map_tmp_end = truncate_job("end", dataset_name, bq_mapping_tmp_table, bq_job_region)
        update_view = create_view_job(sql_view_script, dataset_name, bq_job_region)
        chain(map_to_bq, merge_map, truncate_map_tmp_end, update_view)
    
    chain(set_variables, truncate_map_tmp_start, [process_maf_files, process_mapping])
```

Comment: once your task is in state `up_for_retry`, check the logs of that task in airflow UI to understand why it failed

Comment: There aren't errors or warnings

Comment: If you do the same operation (Dataflow jobs in parallel) without TaskGroup, have you the same behavior ?

Comment: For the up_for_retry task, if the Airflow UI doesn’t give you error logs, you can also check Composer logs in Cloud Logging.

Comment: @MazlumTosun I need TaskGroup because the maf_to_bq tasks are dinamically created based on a dynamic parameter (list of files path) configured in the set_variables_conf task. In Cloud Logging there aren't any logs that can help me to identify a possible error or mistake

Comment: Please may you share the DAG code please ?

Comment: @MazlumTosun I have edited the question with the code. The maf_to_bq task is returned by the function and it is BeamRunPythonPipelineOperator.